# ¿Cómo ordenar correctamente queues en C?

Tags: c, ordenamiento, queue

¡Hola! Estoy haciendo un programa en C y necesito ordenar una cola circular (queue) según la edad de las personas que registro en la cola. Hice un método de ordenamiento, tal vez muy poco profesional pero parecía funcionar, hasta que en la sexta vez que ingresaba un dato, el programa dejaba de responder. Adjunto el código, esperando que alguno de ustedes pueda ayudarme con este problema:)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ElementoCola{
    char nombre[70];
    int edad;
    struct ElementoCola *siguiente;
};

struct Limites{
    int elementos;
    struct ElementoCola *inicio;
    struct ElementoCola *final;
};


int InicializaCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular){
    struct Limites *pTemp=(struct Limites*)malloc(sizeof(struct Limites));
    pTemp->elementos=0;
    pTemp->inicio=NULL;
    pTemp->final=NULL;
    (*ColaCircular)=pTemp;
}

int InsertarCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular, char *nombre, int edad);
int MostrarCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular);
void OrdenaCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct Limites *colacircular;
    char nombre[70];
    int edad, sizeCola, opcion;

    InicializaCola(&colacircular);
    do{
        printf("\n\t\tCOLA CIRCULAR\n\n");
        printf("\t[1]: Agregar usuario\n\t[2]: Ver lista de usuarios\n\t[3]: Salir\n\n\tOpcion: ");
        scanf("%i",&opcion);

        switch(opcion){
            case 1:{
                printf("Ingresa nombre: ");
                scanf("%s", nombre);
                printf("Ingresa edad: ");
                scanf("%i", &edad);
                InsertarCola(&colacircular, nombre, edad);
                OrdenaCola(&colacircular);
                printf("Datos agregados a la cola\n\n");
                break;
            };
            case 2:{
                MostrarCola(&colacircular);
                break;
            };
            case 3:{
                printf("Hasta luego!");
                return 0;
                break;
            };
            default:{
                printf("Dato invalido\n");
                break;
            };
        }
    }
    while(opcion!=3);
    return 0;
}

int InsertarCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular, char *nombre, int edad){
    struct ElementoCola *pNuevo=(struct ElementoCola*)malloc(sizeof(struct ElementoCola));

    if(!pNuevo){
        printf("No se pudo reservar memoria\n");
        return 0;
    }

    strcpy(pNuevo->nombre,nombre);
    pNuevo->edad=edad;
    pNuevo->siguiente=NULL;

    if((*ColaCircular)->inicio==NULL){  
        (*ColaCircular)->inicio=pNuevo;
        (*ColaCircular)->final=pNuevo;
    }
    else{
        (*ColaCircular)->final->siguiente=pNuevo;
        (*ColaCircular)->final=pNuevo;
    }
    ((*ColaCircular)->final)->siguiente=(*ColaCircular)->inicio;
    (*ColaCircular)->elementos++;
    return 0;
}

int MostrarCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular){
    struct ElementoCola *pActual=(*ColaCircular)->inicio;
    int contador=0;

    if(pActual==NULL){
        printf("Cola vacia\n\n");
    }
    while(contador<((*ColaCircular)->elementos)){
        printf("Nombre: %s\nEdad: %i\n\n",pActual->nombre, pActual->edad);
        pActual=pActual->siguiente;
        contador++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void OrdenaCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular){
    int *vector, i, j, auxiliar;
    struct ElementoCola *pActual=(*ColaCircular)->inicio;
    struct Limites *ColaAuxiliar;
    InicializaCola(&ColaAuxiliar);

    vector=(int*)malloc(((*ColaCircular)->elementos)*sizeof(int));
    if(vector==NULL) printf("No se pudo reservar espacio");

    for(i=0; i<((*ColaCircular)->elementos); i++){
        vector[i]=pActual->edad;
        pActual=pActual->siguiente;
    }

    for(i=0; i<((*ColaCircular)->elementos); i++){
        for(j=0; j<((*ColaCircular)->elementos); j++){
            if(vector[j]>vector[j+1]){
                auxiliar=vector[j];
                vector[j]=vector[j+1];
                vector[j+1]=auxiliar;
            }
        }
    }

    i=1;
    while(i<=((*ColaCircular)->elementos)){
        if(vector[i]==pActual->edad){
            InsertarCola(&ColaAuxiliar, pActual->nombre, pActual->edad);
            pActual->edad=0;
            i++;
        }
        else pActual=pActual->siguiente;
    }

    struct ElementoCola *pAuxiliar=ColaAuxiliar->inicio;
    pActual=(*ColaCircular)->inicio;
    for(i=0; i<((*ColaCircular)->elementos); i++){
        strcpy(pActual->nombre,pAuxiliar->nombre);
        pActual->edad=pAuxiliar->edad;
        pActual=pActual->siguiente;
        pAuxiliar=pAuxiliar->siguiente;
    }

    free(vector);
}
```

Como podrán ver, utilicé el método de bubble sort para crear una cola auxiliar que me permitiera sobreescribir la cola original, y como comentaba, funciona parcialmente hasta que agrego un sexto dato y deja de responder el programa

Comment: Hay un error de concepto. No se puede ordenar una cola circular, más bien, esa operación no se le puede hacer a una cola, porque estarías alterando el orden de los elementos que van entrando a la cola. Una lista si se puede ordenar, pero una cola no (no admite la operación ordenar).

Comment: ¿Desde que línea de código deja de funcionar el programa?

Comment: En este caso, ¿qué otra propuesta hay para mantener los datos ordenados dentro de una cola?

Comment: En teoría, todo lo correspondiente a la función OrdenaCola() "falla" ya que si en el main dejo de ponerla, la cola recibe datos sin problemas. Sin embargo, se supone que la función OrdenaCola() ingresa los datos de las edades dentro de un vector dinamico creado al tamaño de elementos de la cola, después ordena el vector con bubble sort, crea una cola auxiliar en la que va añadiendo los datos según la coincidencia en las edades y al final, como la cola circular tiene un inicio y un final para hacer la unión, un apuntador se coloca al inicio de la cola circular y sobreescribe la cola circular

Comment: Respondiendo a la pregunta del anterior comentario, la propuesta sería usar una lista en vez de una cola. Ya que la lista si le puedes agregar la operación de ordenar, ten en cuenta que el término listas y colas hacen referencia a un TDA o interfaz, no se enfocan a una estructura de datos en particular. En fin, con respecto a tu problema, le recomiendo que haga una depuración en la parte donde guardas los elementos en el vector e imprime los valores si realmente están ahí.. Así de a poco encuentras en que parte está el error o su otra opción es utilizar algún depurador.

Comment: Por ejemplo, podrías usar el depurador `gdb` y decirme la línea exacta donde se produce error, que por cierto, aún no sé a que te referis que el programa no responde. ¿Te sale un mensaje donde dice que el programa dejo de funcionar?

Comment: Lo consideraré, mi afán de a fuerza usar colas circulares es porque tengo un proyecto universitario, el cual dice "los usuarios se encuentran en un grupos rotatorios ordenados por edad [...] TIP: (Una Lista de pilas de colas circulares)", aun no he comenzado con la implementación del resto, sin embargo, voy a modificar el post y poner el programa completo, ¿te parece? En sí no me marca un error como tal tipo violación de segmento o algo así, sino que yo ingreso cinco datos de personas ajá y me sale mi confirmación de que que el dato se ha agregado a la cola, pero al ingresar un sexto dato...

Comment: ... El programa se "cicla" por así decirlo, ya no me deja introducir otro dato, simplemente se queda ahí y ya:( Modifico el post con el codigo completo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109128/discussion-between-zule-luis-and-mrdave1999).

Comment: No es necesario usar punteros dobles aquí. `InicializaCola` debe ser `void InicializaCola(struct Limites *)` y no debe hacer ninguna asignación dinámica. Llámalo: `struct Limites cola; InicializaCola(&cola);` Todas las demás funciones también deben aceptar `struct Limites*` y no `struct Limites **`. También, no poner el tipo `int` en una función que no devuelve `int`. Solo una nota al margen.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por los tips, haré las respectivas modificaciones al código!! Por el momento solucioné los errores que tenía y me encargaré de pulir el código, mil gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ordenar la cola, modifiqué el código quitando el método de ordenamiento e ir acomodando en su lugar los valores tan pronto se fueran ingresando

```
int InsertarCola(struct Limites **ColaCircular, char *nombre, int edad){
    struct ElementoCola *pNuevo=(struct ElementoCola*)malloc(sizeof(struct ElementoCola));

    if(!pNuevo){
        printf("No se pudo reservar memoria para el elemento cola\n");
        return 0;
    }

    strcpy(pNuevo->nombre,nombre);
    pNuevo->edad=edad;
    pNuevo->siguiente=NULL;

    if((*ColaCircular)->inicio==NULL){    
        (*ColaCircular)->inicio=pNuevo;
        (*ColaCircular)->final=pNuevo;
    }
    else{
        if(edad>(*ColaCircular)->inicio->edad){
            if(edad>(*ColaCircular)->final->edad){
                (*ColaCircular)->final->siguiente=pNuevo;
                (*ColaCircular)->final=(*ColaCircular)->final->siguiente;
            }
            else{
                struct ElementoCola *pActual=(*ColaCircular)->inicio->siguiente;
                struct ElementoCola *pAnterior=(*ColaCircular)->inicio;
                while(edad>pActual->edad){
                    pAnterior=pActual;
                    pActual=pActual->siguiente;
                }
                pAnterior->siguiente=pNuevo;
                pNuevo->siguiente=pActual;
            }
        }
        else{
            pNuevo->siguiente=(*ColaCircular)->inicio;
            (*ColaCircular)->inicio=pNuevo;
        }
    }

    ((*ColaCircular)->final)->siguiente=(*ColaCircular)->inicio;
    (*ColaCircular)->elementos++;
    return 0;
}
```

El código no está completamente optimizado, sin embargo, tal vez pueda resultarle útil a alguien. ¡Gracias por su ayuda!